# How to make a 500+ psi water gun staff

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, compressed-air

I would like to create a life size lego Bionicle Aqua axe(gali nuva Type or gali master of water Type). The problem is unlike The trident in this video:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NK6MWt7vpVE&t=641s

I would like it to be able to be used underwater and not rely on co2. I was wondering if there’s a way to charge a piece of brass/pvc pipe To 500+ psi without co2 gas but still have it compact and waterproof. Another bonus would be if it could not have to be charged with a bicycle pump but rather some system built into the staff.

Comment: Gunpowder comes to mind.

Comment: Maybe a pump for a PCP air gun.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal of 500 psi is optimistic in my opinion. If you've found a bicycle pump with near that capability, you've probably located a bicycle suspension high pressure pump. I used those terms in Amazon search and found most to be in the 200-300 psi range, with one exception.

There's a [400 psi pump advertised](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08BR6CTFN). It's rather small:

[image: 400 psi hand pump]

but that's to be expected as there's always a trade-off between volume and pressure. It's relatively easy to create high pressure if you can tolerate a few cubic centimeters of volume per stroke.

You suggest to build a system into the staff, and this small unit may be reasonably incorporated into your design. Of course, one must be on the surface to recharge, which could be rather inconvenient, especially if the charge chamber is going to provide only one or two shots.

[image: detail view of pump]

All images courtesy of Amazon linked site.